# New Spot Instances bid options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Spot instances console has changed and comes with some new options. I have been looking but couldn't find information of how some of those new options work. There is a new **automatic bid option** that I haven't been able to find any explanations of how it works so I wonder if anyone here knows a little more about it (the description is explanatory but it is a little bit short).

[image: automatic bid 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> New automated bidding on the Spot Requests console allows you to cap
>   your maximum price automatically at EC2 On-demand rates, a bidding
>   best practice which can help significantly reduce interruption with
>   minimal impact to cost savings. ([Source](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/new-amazon-ec2-spot-console-now-supports-spot-fleet-and-spot-blocks/))

Using automated bidding is useful because it can help reduce instance terminations due to the spot price rising above your bid. At a minimum you'll pay the spot price and the maximum you'll pay is the instance type's On-Demand price. Contrast it with setting your max price - if the current spot price exceeds your maximum price your instance will be terminated. This method has the trade-off that you control the maximum price.

If you want to use spot instances and want better assurance your jobs will complete without being terminated while in progress, automated bidding is your best choice. If you are starting up temporary, additional servers to help reduce load and it's ok if they get terminated then setting your max price is probably more cost efficient.

Comment: so we can say that using the automatic bid the instances will never terminate? Or can the spot price rise above the on-demand price?

Comment: The spot price will not rise above the on-demand price when using the automated bidding so you won't spend more than the on-demand price. A spot price can go above the on-demand price, and in this case, your instance will be terminated. Relevant link: http://serverfault.com/q/425794/297130

Comment: Very useful link! Anyways, as this option chooses the AZ where instances are cheaper, it's highly probable that you'll never reach the on-demand price.

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks!